# How to get access and refresh tokens from the response URI after granting consent

Tags: python, bing-ads-api

unfortunately I can't go any further with the bingads api. After the oauth I will be redirected to an empty page.

You need to provide consent for the application to access your Bing Ads accounts. After you have granted consent in the web browser for the application to access your Bing Ads accounts, please enter the response URI that includes the authorization 'code' parameter:

I don't no what to paste here in

Answer (score 1):

The empty page that opens in your browser should have a URI address. It could look something like this `https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx&state=NameOfAcc&ab=1234`. Copy and paste the whole address into the command line.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/authentication-oauth#managingoauthtokens